# Android Inline Images in Email

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

Any one can suggest how to add images in email body ?
I tried it, but no answer.

Here is my code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "gmail@gmail.com" });
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Photo");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + _path));
sendIntent.setType("image/png;text/html");

String htmlecode = 
    "<html><b>Bold Text works perfectly</b>" +
    "<img width='48' height='48' alt='' " +
    "src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Basketball.png' />" +
    "</html>";

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmlecode, imgGetter, null));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

wat's wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457457/android-intent-send-an-email-with-image-attachment). They suggest using:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Myimage.jpeg"));
```