# Android\Intent: Send an email with image attachment

Tags: android, email

The email is being received on by the recipient, but without the attachment. Here is the code, any expert knows where did I go wrong?

```
 Intent messageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

String aEmailList[] = { "mymailgmail.com" };
messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);

messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
...    
messageIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
File downloadedPic = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "MyApp.jpg");

messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(downloadedPic));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(messageIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_pic)));
```

I get:

> file:// attachment path must point to file://sdcard. Ignoring attachment file://...file name is MyApp.jpg

I am not getting image, only above text message. Thanks.

Comment: same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try below code...

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("application/image");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{strEmail}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test Subject"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From My App"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Myimage.jpeg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: I tried using it, but the attachment is missing in the received email. Any idea why is it so?

Comment: Check your path of attachment file.. i think it may be wrong.

Comment: path is correct and the file is also seen as attached with the email on sender's end. But once the email is sent, attachment not visible neither on sender nor receiver.

Comment: help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook

Comment: how to attach multiple files ..?

Comment: @Amritpal that is exactly what happens when the file you passed in the intent is private to your application. Try copying the file to a public location on the device before and share it with that new url (ex. copy it to the External Storage folder first).

Comment: @EktaDushanj : What's the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 10):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.setType("application/image");

Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + filepath);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: can someone please help me how to use this code to send image from my assets folder

Comment: You may not even need the "setType" because that would conflict with your having done 'setType("text/html"), right? It seems the Intent.EXTRA_STREAM figures out the type for the attachment; at least it worked for me when I removed the second "setType". And the mail arrived at the destination MTA with Content-Type: image/jpeg;
 name="photo000001.jpg" on the message part for the image.

Comment: can you explain how can I get this filepath ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//add below in Manifest file  
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>

// create xml folder inside file name file_paths.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  -->
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="data/data/com.cw.getmycolor/cache" />
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.cw.getmycolor/files/Pictures" />

    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
    <external-path
        name="share"
        path="/" />

</paths>

// send method email

    private void shareApp() {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("application/image");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"demo@gmail.com");

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new 

    File(uri.getPath())));/*getImageContentUri(this,new File(uri.getPath())));*/
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."), 201);

        }
```