# How to send drawable to twitter intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

I have made an android app ,I want to share a drawable to twitter,Currently I have done this way for text,But can any buddy tell me how to attach image to intent to share via twitter ,Thank you in advance,My code is as below:

```
public void shareTwitterIntent() {
        String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=3SManiquines";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (from [How to attach a Bitmap when launching ACTION_SEND intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160593/how-to-attach-a-bitmap-when-launching-action-send-intent) -- perhaps a duplicate?):

```
String pathofBmp = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,"title", null);
Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
final Intent emailIntent1 = new Intent(     android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
emailIntent1.setType("image/png");
```