# android.os.FileUriExposedException: file.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Tags: android, image, camera, onclick, media

I try to do a button that open the camera and take picture. my code is here

```
//for imports check on bottom of this code block

public class HomeProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//Button camera
public static final String TAG = HomeProfileActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 0;
public static final int REQUEST_TAKE_VIDEO = 1;
public static final int REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO = 2;
public static final int REQUEST_PICK_VIDEO = 3;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 4;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 5;

private Uri mMediaUri;
private ImageView photobutton;
private Button buttonUploadImage, buttonTakeImage;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_profile);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.buttonTakeImage)
void takePhoto() {
    mMediaUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (mMediaUri == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "There was a problem accessing your device's external storage.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
        startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewImageActivity.class);
            intent.setData(mMediaUri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, there was an error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int mediaType) {
    // check for external storage
    if (isExternalStorageAvailable()) {
        // get the URI

        // 1. Get the external storage directory
        File mediaStorageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        // 2. Create a unique file name
        String fileName = "";
        String fileType = "";
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        if (mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            fileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp;
            fileType = ".jpg";
        } else if (mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            fileName = "VID_" + timeStamp;
            fileType = ".mp4";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        // 3. Create the file
        File mediaFile;
        try {
            mediaFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, fileType, mediaStorageDir);
            Log.i(TAG, "File: " + Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));

            // 4. Return the file's URI
            return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error creating file: " +
                        mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + fileName + fileType);
            }
        }

        // something went wrong
        return null;
    }

private boolean isExternalStorageAvailable(){
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
```

I have also a problem with `startActivityForResult` in the method onclick
and the import `java.text.SimpleDateFormat;` also jump in the exception runtime
i am working with buildtoolsversion sdk 25

Comment: `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+, with a `targetSdkVersion` of 24 or higher. Use `FileProvider` instead, as I demonstrate in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider). See also [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html) and [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html).

Comment: Please see the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: Easy explanation available here: [link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en)

Answer (score 167):

Besides the solution using the FileProvider, there is another way to work around this. Simply put

```
 StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
 StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

in Application.onCreate() method. In this way the VM ignores the file URI exposure.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks, anything i should know for a possible future problem or i'm good for a while?

Comment: StrictMode is disabled by default, and users need to enter "Developer's mode" in their Android to enable it.
That makes the solution of using StrictMode irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, working for me.

Test Device Android : 7.0
targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Should I wrap this with only SDK version 24 or above

Comment: @rahul sondarva Could you please answer the above questions..even I am having the same.

Comment: @AbuNayem you should use a FileProvider, that's the right solution. This answer is a hack.

Answer (score 50):

This info is from:
[FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html)

> This is only thrown for applications targeting N or higher.
>   Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to share
>   file:// Uri, but it's strongly discouraged.

So if your `app/build.gradle` file's `compileSdkVersion` (build target) is Android N (API level 24) or greater, this error is thrown if you write a file that can possibly get accessed by other apps.  Most importantly, here is how you are supposed to do it moving forward:

taken from here:
[FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

Change:

```
return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
```

to be

```
return FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName()+".fileprovider", mediaFile);
```

Note: if you control `mydomain.com` you could also replace `getPackageName()+".fileprovider"` with `"com.mydomain.fileprovider"` (the same goes for your `AndroidManifest.xml` below.

Also you need to add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file right before your `</application>` tag

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

Then you need to add a file named `filepaths.xml` to your `app/src/main/res/xml` directory with the following contents

```
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="Pictures" path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Note: for anybody else, we used `external-files-path` above, since Omer used `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` in the code.  For any other location, please check [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles) under the "Specifying Available Files" section and change `external-files-path` to one of the following based on where your files are located:

```
files-path
cache-path
external-path
external-files-path
external-cache-path
```

Also, revise `Pictures` above to be your folder name.

One important anti-pattern to avoid is you should **NOT** use `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {` to allow you to do it the old way, because it is not their ***Android version*** that requires this, it's your ***build version*** (I missed this the first time I coded it).

I know this is more work, however, this allows Android to allow only the other app you're sharing with, temporary access to the file, which is more secure for the user's privacy.

Comment: Just quick edit: the path="pictures" is case sensitive. When using Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES on my end, I had to capitalize it as path="Pictures", otherwise it couldn't figure out a path.

Comment: @DaveSanders Thank you for noticing that, I have updated my answer to reflect the case of Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, which evaluates to "Pictures" (Title case)

Comment: please not that androidX verrion of `FileProvider` has package `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`

Answer (score -3):

```
Add the below code where the SharingIntent called:-

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24){
                    try{
                        Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
                        m.invoke(null);
                        shareImage(Uri.fromFile(new File(Path)));
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```