# Untitled is shown instead of file name while sharing on whatsapp through android app

Tags: java, android

I have written code to share `.txt` file  on my device to whatsapp. However text file gets shared but instead of showing the name of the `.txt` file it shows untitled. Here is my code.I have also attached screen shot of whatsapp screen after sharing the file.

```
public static void shareTextToSocialMedia(Context c,String sFilePath)
{
    //share pdf via WhatsApp
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(sFilePath);

    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    c.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share report using"));
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have attached my image for first time here. So failed to write the  discription of it. please click on "enter image description here" to view the image.

Comment: Thanks for editting Prem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try this it will help for you

**Share an txt file from your app**

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" +   "abc.txt");
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share file with"));
```

**Share Image from your App Example**

```
File f=new File("full image path");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+f.getAbsolutePath());
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setType("image/*");
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image File"));
```

**Share Image directly to WhatsApp from your app**

```
File f=new File("full image path");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+f.getAbsolutePath());
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setType("image/*");
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image File"));
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue got resolved.The code is correct.The path was wrong.
 I added file:// to the path.I set the path of .txt file like this,
"file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"Notes"+File.separator+sName+".txt";
[View attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCGNK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is using FileProvider as this can lead to FileUriExposedException

You can refer this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46761554/2793036