# Attach image using Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I'm trying to attach an image using different applications with the following code:

```
val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test example")
sendIntent.type = "image/png"
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(logo.absolutePath))
startActivity(sendIntent)
```

The image that is attached is generated with this code:

```
// Generate file for application logo
val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath
val logo = File(path, "logo.png")

// If logo doesn't exist
if (!logo.exists())
{
    // Create new file
    logo.createNewFile()

    // Save application logo to new file
    val fOut = FileOutputStream(logo)
    val image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut)
    fOut.flush()
    fOut.close()
}
```

But when I try to open GMAIL with this intent, only text shows app with an error: `Couldn't attach file`.

What am I missing?

> EDIT

Here is another solution: [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251634/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-jpg-exposed-beyond-app-through-clipdata/45569709#45569709)

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

Comment: I don't this is your fault , It's mostly because Gmail mark this stream as an attachment , plz attach the whole error log about Gmail.

Comment: You should use FileProvider to obtain a Uri to the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Android N you have to use `FileProvider` to Obtain `Uri`.

Please see below example for file sharing.

```
ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        File file = new File(<Your File Path>);
        Uri uri;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(DetailActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        } else {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
        files.add(uri);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Product Sharing");
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ANY TEXT MESSAGE");
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Place below code in AndroidManifest.xml in Application tag

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
```

and place filepath.xml file in xml resource directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send file without file provider. Gmail, for example, doesn't request `READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions, so it cannot access your file. You must use file provider with `GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. You can read more here

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider
2. https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing
3. https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file