# Android how to attach an image byte[] to an email as an attachment?

Tags: java, c#, android, email, xamarin

I'm writing this in Xamarin but the answer can be for Android Java (and I'll translate) or Xamarain.

I have a c# byte array (named attachment) of the contents of an gif like image so I cannot turn it into an image object as the contents inside would be lost. Think of it as a byte array of a file. I want to attach this image to an email. I have the following code.

```
//Create the email intent.
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);

//Add a flag to let the system know it can start this activity.
emailIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

//Put the subject in the email.
emailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, subject);

//Put the body in the email.
emailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, body);

//Add the attachment.
emailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, attachment);

//Set the intent type to the intent type of the email.
emailIntent.SetType("message/rfc822");

//Create a chooser intent to ask the user to choose the application for email.
Intent finalIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email");
```

When I hit the code, it asks for an email program, I chose GMail, and I see my subject and body but no attachment.

How can I attach the byte array to the email to get it to attach?

**Edit**
This question was marked as a duplicate. Here is why this question is NOT the same as [How to attach a Bitmap when launching ACTION_SEND intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160593/how-to-attach-a-bitmap-when-launching-action-send-intent)

That question:
1. Involves sending a bitmap. I don't have a bitmap but rather a in memory byte array. As mentioned, I CANNOT turn this byte array into a bitmap image as the contents inside will become compressed and modified. Even if I could get the bitmap to not be modified, every answer in that question runs a .compress on the bitmap.
2. This byte array should not be saved to the device for security. I generate the byte array and send it off. I would need a way to attach it in memory and not saving it to the file system.

Comment: @Jason I edited the question to explain why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: as best as I can tell, you have to save it to a file in order to send it as an attachment.  You can save the data to file without converting it to a bitmap.  If security is a concern, delete the file after you send it.

Comment: I see no byte array. Is 'attachment' a stream?

Comment: Please show how you would attach a file.

Comment: Which name should the email app use for the bytes? The receiver wants to see a file name i think. Or how would the email app or the receiving email app know that it is an image?

Comment: Save the bytes of the array to private internal memory of your app. There no other app has access. Use a file provider to serve the file to the email app. Delete the file the next time you are going to send a file.

Comment: The email app expects a file or an uri for the reasons i mentioned.

Comment: @greenapps The "attachment" variable is a byte[] of the image.