# How to Send/attach multiple images

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I want to send multiple images. 
I tried `setType("image/jpeg")` also, I see this question posted in a lot of places, but didn't find correct answer

```
val emailIntent = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE, Uri.parse("mailto:" + context?.resources?.getString(R.string.email)))
emailIntent.setType("application/image")
val uris = ArrayList<Uri>()

for (file in filePaths) {
    val fileIn = File(file)
    val u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn)
    uris.add(u)
}
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject)
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody)
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris)

context?.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14457735/3673259 It said `application/image` instead of `image/jpeg`

Comment: @Joshua  
I tried both application/image and image/jpeg but non of them are working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` Intent doesn't take a `data` argument. So get rid of the `Uri.parse("mailto:...` argument in the constructor. Put the email address into `EXTRA_EMAIL` instead. Note that this extra is holding a string array, not a simple string.
- The correct type to use is `image/jpeg` if all of the attachments are JPEGs, otherwise use `image/*`.
- Sharing `file://` URIs is being a bad Android citizen. It requires the receiving app to hold the storage permission. Use [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) instead and don't forget to add the flag `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`.